# when rte_hash_lookup_data() returns 0?

Tags: c++, networking, hash, lookup, dpdk

I am using dpdk-20.08. According to the documentation, rte_hash_lookup_data() returns either a positive value that can be used by the caller as an offset into an array of user data or -EINVAL or -ENOENT. But I keep receiving 0 as a return value. Can anyone explain when 0 is returned in rte_hash lookup?

Comment: Please update with example code, code snippet, entry in the table, entry used for lookup to reproduce the error.

Comment: returning 0 is an error?

Comment: please refer http://doc.dpdk.org/api/rte__hash_8h.html#a1bd8f85b9c99eea0a619acc1d6ce2b2c, where the rerun value is positive value (including 0) which act as an offset. I have requested clearly to share example code or code snippet, entries in table and entry used to test the hash table. Without these it Is not easy to reproduce the error. So please share your code snippet to check if indeed `entry 0 is indeed the hash entry been looked up`

Comment: Thank you. I just needed to know this. I thought positive value does not include 0. Now I understand that 0 is returned when the key is present and the offset is 0.

Comment: As I have mentioned in above 2 comments, I am not clear if you are claiming there is bug in DPDK hash library as your test case is returning `0`. In order to properly evaluate I need the code snippet, hash entry, hash lookup value to confirm if it si correct behaviour or not.